# How long does the RAM continue to hold Prefetching for whilst motion tracking?

Tags: mesh, camera, tracking

I looked through similar questions but can't really find anything on it.

When you prefetch a video in motion tracking, it stores it on the RAM for quick access, that bit I get.

My question is, how long does the RAM continue to hold it for?

I noticed last night I was working on tracking and adding my mesh into the scene and my RAM was still being used for the prefetch, this was a good 3 or 4 hours.

Secondary bonus question: Is RAM at risk of being damaged if used all the while we are editing in vfx/layout mode?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

Your PC will hold that data in memory pretty much as long as feasible.  It's possible if your PC was running low on memory Blender would be told to relinquish it.

RAM stores voltage in capacitors which are actively maintained by refreshing the voltage levels many times per second.  This is fundamentally different from an SSD which has the capacity for long term storage and uses a self-destructive method out of necessity.  Electrons are shot through a membrane which can store them even while power is disconnected but this will wear out the membrane eventually.  This is why SSDs have a write limit, and it's why SSDs go through the trouble of "wear-leveling" so that the entire drive wears out around the same time.

RAM suffers no such damage from regular use, and will only fail with age (hours used) or electrical damage like any other solid state PC component.